# How can I set the fee payer different wallet?

Tags: transfer, fees

In Solana, how can I set fee payer as receiver wallet ?

I will transfer funds from A to B but B needs to pay the fee.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless B signs the transaction. Solana allows you to set a different wallet as fee payer of a transaction, however that different wallet MUST sign the transaction. If you want to send funds from wallet `A` to `B` with `B` paying the fee. Both `A` and `B` would need to sign the transaction.

- `A` would authorize that "Yes I want to allow movement of my funds"
- `B` would authorize that "Yes I want to pay fees from my wallet for
  this movement (transaction)"

You can check out [Octane](https://github.com/solana-labs/octane) if you want to implement gasless transactions or just in general have a starting point to sending transactions with a different fee payer.

Comment: Yes, B needs to sign to pay fees. I am not tech guy. I just need to set this because of scammer took over my wallet A. The only way to save my funds I need to set another wallet for fee payer.